# Close Built-in User agent switcher in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent

When I try to Inspect Element using Chrome's Developer Console (using Right click → Inspect Element), I'm always presented with a User Agent switcher interface like below:

[image]

This is very annoying and I can't for the life of me figure out how to exit this. For now, I'm using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open the Developer Console (the User-Agent Switcher doesn't appear when I do that, but I don't know why).

My question is two-fold:

- How can I exit the User-Agent Switcher?
- How can I disable it permanently (assuming that's possible)?

Note: I'm using Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.102 and don't have any additional extensions installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the develop console, it stores the layout settings as you last left them. So, if you click on the Hide Drawer button [image] on the top right hand side to hide the bottom part (User-Agent Switcher) and it should not appear back on again.

There are also options to disable the Emulation tab in the Drawer ("User-Agent Swticher") by clicking on the Gear Icon labeled "Settings" [image] and unchecking both "Show 'Emulation' view in console drawer." and "Show 'Rendering' view in console drawer." settings under the Appearance category. The picture of the settings panel is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

At the top right, click the blue icon that looks like this:

[image]

This collapses the tab area that contains the Console, Search, and Emulation tabs. You may later click the gray version of the same icon to expand the area.

It will remain closed until you open it again after which it will remain open until you close it.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the escape key to exit.

For more keyboard shortcuts you can read the Google Devtools docs:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, unfortunately.